# which view will get first preference in below mentioned applicationcontext....?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"  />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jasper-views.xml"   />
```

which view will get first preference in above applicationcontext....pls explain me. if method returns ABC as a view and abc.jsp and abc is also present in jasper view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both those classes implement [Ordered](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) interface, so You can control the order the get called by setting the `order` property value, i.e.:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    p:suffix=".jsp"
    p:order="1" />

<bean id="jasperViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jasper-views.xml"
    p:order="2" />
```

By default (no `order` values set) I'd assume they to be called in the same order they're declared in the XML.

Comment: thanks for the reply. you mean to say if i do not write P:order then it will resolve it in a order ther're declared but if suppose jspviewresolver view is missing and if it comes first then will it produce any error or it will check for another view resolver please guide me..!